# How does Laravels task scheduling work without persisting the last completed date?

Tags: laravel

Laravel is (correctly) running scheduled tasks via the `App\Console\Kernel@schedule` method. It does this *without* the need for a persistance layer. Previously ran scheduled tasks aren't saved to the database or stored in anyway.

How is this "magic" achieved? I want to have a deeper understanding.

I have looked through the source, and I can see it is somewhat achieved by rounding down the current date and diffing that to the schedule frequency, along with the fact that it is required to run every minute, it can say with a certain level of confidence that it should run a task. That is my interpretation, but I still can't fully grasp *how* it is guaranteeing to run on schedule and how it handles failure or things being off by a few seconds.

**EDIT** Edit due to clarity issue pointed out in comment.

By "a few seconds" I mean how does the "round down" method work, even when it is ran every minute, but not at the same second - example: first run 00:01.00, 00:01:02, 00:02:04

Maybe to clarify further, and to assist in understanding *how* it works, is there any boundary guarantees on how it functions? If ran multiple times per minute will it execute per minute tasks multiple times in the minute?

Comment: Do you have any insight into the per-second schedule guarantee you mention, I can't find any reference to it and haven't heard of such a thing before. As far as I know, it is not guaranteed that your command will run with _to the second_ accuracy nor is it guaranteed it won't run twice if you run `schedule:run` twice in a minute. The scheduler knows that it is run every minute, it knows what the current time is, so if you say "every 10 minutes" the scheduler knows "if the current minute is 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 then run the task".

Comment: Poor wording on my behalf - I will update "few seconds" - cheers Sam

Comment: Looking at [the tests](https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/e6c8aa0e39d8f91068ad1c299546536e9f25ef63/tests/Console/Scheduling) we can get a rough idea of what is expected behaviour. There does look to be some persistence, as there are tests to ensure the same command isn't ran more than once. Generally tests are a good place to look to understand _how_ something is expected to behave.

Comment: I agree - and the level of persistence is what I am trying to understand

Comment: The tests looking interesting, esp the frequency one. Its testing against a cron signature, so curious if the schedule task receives the cron params and checks if it matches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cronjob can not guarantee seconds precisely. That is why generally no cronjob interval is less than a minute. So, in reality, it doesn't handle "things being off by a few seconds."

What happens in laravel is this, after running scheduling command for the first time the server asks "Is there a queued job?" every minute. If none, it doesn't do anything.

For example, take the "daily" cronjob. Scheduler doesn't need to know when was the last time it ran the task or something like this. When it encounters the daily cronjob it simply checks if it is midnight. If it is midnight it runs the job.

Also, take "every thirty minute" cronjob. Maybe you registered the cronjob at 10:25. But still the first time it will run on 10:30, not on 10:55. It doesn't care what time you registered or when was the last time it ran. It only checks if the current minute is "00" or divisible by thirty. So at 10:30 it will run. Again, it will run on 11:00. and so on.

Similarly a ten minute cronjob by default will only check if the current minute is divisible by ten or not. So, regardless of the time you registered the command it will run only on XX:00, XX:10, XX:20 and so on.

That is why by default it doesn't need to store previously ran scheduled task. However, you can store it into a file if you want for monitoring purpose.

Comment: The first bit makes (midnight), and I was about to tick it as the answer. But the second bit throws me again - how does it know on the first time to run at 10:30 and not the next time 10:25 swings around again

Comment: Check my answer now. Hope it makes sense now.